# File pond rename file before upload to the server if the file with the same name exist

Tags: javascript, php, filepond

Hello I am using filepond for uploading multiple files from here https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/getting-started/examples/

I Want to upload multiple files with the same name.
for example if 'file1.pdf' is exist then rename file before upload it to the server like 'file1_1.pdf'

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us example of what you have tried?